# Docker Magento 2

Tags: magento2, docker

I try create magento 2 docker image, but after run `docker-compose up --build` i have some problem, build process is die on step to install magento(`RUN php bin/magento setup:install...`),

```
getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

In InstallCommand.php line 264:

Parameter validation failed
```

but if i remove that step and try do the same command in my container, magento will successfull installed. Please help me to resolve this problem. Here is link to gihub https://github.com/chaikivskyi/magento2-docker.

Comment: i can connect to mysql with adminer with the same parameters as i'am using in magento 2 setup command

Comment: Use https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento this one. This is better m2 docker.

Comment: @SohelRana it doesn't fix my problem